# Traefik configuration to watch a particular kubernetes namespace doesn't works

Tags: kubernetes, namespaces, traefik, kubernetes-ingress

I deployed the same chart (contains traefik as sub-chart) to different namespaces of a cluster. Both traefik dashboards were showing that every frontend has 2 corresponding backends.
[image]

This could be because traefik was watching ingress objects of all namespaces. So I decided to restrict it to one namespace.

Traefik chart: https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/traefik

values.yaml :

```
## Default values for Traefik
image: traefik
imageTag: 1.7.14
imagePullPolicy: Always
imagePullSecret: ""

nameOverride: ""
fullnameOverride: ""
dependsOn: rest 

restart: Always

## can switch the service type to NodePort if required
serviceType: LoadBalancer
# Set static IP for service
loadBalancerIP: ""
# loadBalancerSourceRanges: []
whiteListSourceRange: []
externalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
replicas: 1

startupArguments:
  - "--api"
  - "--kubernetes"

podDisruptionBudget: {}
  # maxUnavailable: 1
  # minAvailable: 2

# priorityClassName: ""

# rootCAs: []

resources: {}

debug:
  enabled: false

deploymentStrategy:
  type: Recreate
  # rollingUpdate:
  #   maxSurge: 1
  #   maxUnavailable: 0


securityContext: {}
env: {}

nodeSelector: {}
  # key: value
affinity: {}
  # key: value
tolerations: []
# - key: "key"
#   operator: "Equal|Exists"
#   value: "value"
#   effect: "NoSchedule|PreferNoSchedule|NoExecute(1.6 only)"


## Kubernetes ingress filters
kubernetes:
  namespaces:
  - default
  - kube-system
  # endpoint:
  # labelSelector:
  # ingressClass:
  # ingressEndpoint:
  #   hostname: "localhost"
  #   ip: "127.0.0.1"
  #   publishedService: "namespace/servicename"
  #   useDefaultPublishedService: false

proxyProtocol:
  enabled: false
  # trustedIPs is required when enabled
  trustedIPs: []
  # - 10.0.0.0/8
forwardedHeaders:
  enabled: false
  # trustedIPs is required when enabled
  trustedIPs: []
  # - 10.0.0.0/8

## Add arbitrary ConfigMaps to deployment
## Will be mounted to /configs/, i.e. myconfig.json would
## be mounted to /configs/myconfig.json.
configFiles: {}
  # myconfig.json: |
  #   filecontents...

## Add arbitrary Secrets to deployment
## Will be mounted to /secrets/, i.e. file.name would
## be mounted to /secrets/mysecret.txt.
## The contents will be base64 encoded when added
secretFiles: {}
  # mysecret.txt: |
  #   filecontents...

ssl:
  enabled: false
  enforced: false
  permanentRedirect: false
  upstream: false
  insecureSkipVerify: false
  generateTLS: false
  # defaultCN: "example.com"
    # or *.example.com
  defaultSANList: []
    # - example.com
    # - test1.example.com
  defaultIPList: []
    # - 1.2.3.4
  # cipherSuites: []
  # https://docs.traefik.io/configuration/entrypoints/#specify-minimum-tls-version
  # tlsMinVersion: VersionTLS12
  # https://docs.traefik.io/configuration/entrypoints/#strict-sni-checking
  # sniStrict: false
  defaultCert: 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
  defaultKey: 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
  # Basic auth to protect all the routes. Can use htpasswd to generate passwords
  # > htpasswd -n -b testuser testpass
  # > testuser:$apr1$JXRA7j2s$LpVns9vsme8FHN0r.aSt11
  auth: {}
    # basic:
    #   testuser: $apr1$JXRA7j2s$LpVns9vsme8FHN0r.aSt11

kvprovider:
  ## If you want to run Traefik in HA mode, you will need to setup a KV Provider. Therefore you can choose one of
  ## * etcd
  ## * consul
  ## * boltdb
  ## * zookeeper
  ##
  ## ref: https://docs.traefik.io/user-guide/cluster/

  ## storeAcme has to be enabled to support HA Support using acme, but at least one kvprovider is needed
  storeAcme: false
  importAcme: false

  # etcd:
    # endpoint: etcd-service:2379
    # useAPIV3: false
    # watch: true
    # prefix: traefik

    ## Override default configuration template.
    ## For advanced users :)
    ##
    ## Optional
    # filename: consul.tmpl
    # username: foo
    # password: bar
    # tls:
    #   ca: "/etc/ssl/ca.crt"
    #   cert: "/etc/ssl/consul.crt"
    #   key: "/etc/ssl/consul.key"
    #   insecureSkipVerify: true
    #
  # consul:
    # endpoint: consul-service:8500
    # watch: true
    # prefix: traefik

    ## Override default configuration template.
    ## For advanced users :)
    ##
    ## Optional
    # filename: consul.tmpl
    # username: foo
    # password: bar
    # tls:
    #   ca: "/etc/ssl/ca.crt"
    #   cert: "/etc/ssl/consul.crt"
    #   key: "/etc/ssl/consul.key"
    #   insecureSkipVerify: true

    ## only relevant for etcd


acme:
  enabled: false
  email: admin@example.com
  onHostRule: true
  staging: true
  logging: false
  # Configure a Let's Encrypt certificate to be managed by default.
  # This is the only way to request wildcard certificates (works only with dns challenge).
  domains:
    enabled: false
    # List of sets of main and (optional) SANs to generate for
    # for wildcard certificates see https://docs.traefik.io/configuration/acme/#wildcard-domains
    domainsList:
      # - main: "*.example.com"
      # - sans:
      #   - "example.com"
      # - main: "*.example2.com"
      # - sans:
      #   - "test1.example2.com"
      #   - "test2.example2.com"
  ## ACME challenge type: "tls-sni-01", "tls-alpn-01", "http-01" or "dns-01"
  ## Note the chart's default of tls-sni-01 has been DEPRECATED and (except in
  ## certain circumstances) DISABLED by Let's Encrypt. It remains as a default
  ## value in this chart to preserve legacy behavior and avoid a breaking
  ## change. Users of this chart should strongly consider making the switch to
  ## the recommended "tls-alpn-01" (avaialbe since v1.7), dns-01 or http-01
  ## (available since v1.5) challenge.
  challengeType: tls-sni-01
  ## Configure dnsProvider to perform domain verification using dns challenge
  ## Applicable only if using the dns-01 challenge type
  delayBeforeCheck: 0
  resolvers: []
    # - 1.1.1.1:53
    # - 8.8.8.8:53
  dnsProvider:
    name: nil
    existingSecretName: ""
    auroradns:
      AURORA_USER_ID: ""
      AURORA_KEY: ""
      AURORA_ENDPOINT: ""
    azure:
      AZURE_CLIENT_ID: ""
      AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET: ""
      AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID: ""
      AZURE_TENANT_ID: ""
      AZURE_RESOURCE_GROUP: ""
    cloudflare:
      CLOUDFLARE_EMAIL: ""
      CLOUDFLARE_API_KEY: ""
    digitalocean:
      DO_AUTH_TOKEN: ""
    dnsimple:
      DNSIMPLE_OAUTH_TOKEN: ""
      DNSIMPLE_BASE_URL: ""
    dnsmadeeasy:
      DNSMADEEASY_API_KEY: ""
      DNSMADEEASY_API_SECRET: ""
      DNSMADEEASY_SANDBOX: ""
    dnspod:
      DNSPOD_API_KEY: ""
    dreamhost:
      DREAMHOST_API_KEY: ""
    dyn:
      DYN_CUSTOMER_NAME: ""
      DYN_USER_NAME: ""
      DYN_PASSWORD: ""
    exoscale:
      EXOSCALE_API_KEY: ""
      EXOSCALE_API_SECRET: ""
      EXOSCALE_ENDPOINT: ""
    gandi:
      GANDI_API_KEY: ""
    godaddy:
      GODADDY_API_KEY: ""
      GODADDY_API_SECRET: ""
    gcloud:
      GCE_PROJECT: ""
      GCE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE: ""
    linode:
      LINODE_API_KEY: ""
    namecheap:
      NAMECHEAP_API_USER: ""
      NAMECHEAP_API_KEY: ""
    ns1:
      NS1_API_KEY: ""
    otc:
      OTC_DOMAIN_NAME: ""
      OTC_USER_NAME: ""
      OTC_PASSWORD: ""
      OTC_PROJECT_NAME: ""
      OTC_IDENTITY_ENDPOINT: ""
    ovh:
      OVH_ENDPOINT: ""
      OVH_APPLICATION_KEY: ""
      OVH_APPLICATION_SECRET: ""
      OVH_CONSUMER_KEY: ""
    pdns:
      PDNS_API_URL: ""
    rackspace:
      RACKSPACE_USER: ""
      RACKSPACE_API_KEY: ""
    rfc2136:
      RFC2136_NAMESERVER: ""
      RFC2136_TSIG_ALGORITHM: ""
      RFC2136_TSIG_KEY: ""
      RFC2136_TSIG_SECRET: ""
      RFC2136_TIMEOUT: ""
    route53:
      AWS_REGION: ""
      AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ""
      AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ""
    vultr:
      VULTR_API_KEY: ""
  ## Save ACME certs to a persistent volume.
  ## WARNING: If you do not do this and you did not have configured
  ## a kvprovider, you will re-request certs every time a pod (re-)starts
  ## and you WILL be rate limited!
  persistence:
    enabled: true
    annotations: {}
    ## acme data Persistent Volume Storage Class
    ## If defined, storageClassName: <storageClass>
    ## If set to "-", storageClassName: "", which disables dynamic provisioning
    ## If undefined (the default) or set to null, no storageClassName spec is
    ##   set, choosing the default provisioner.  (gp2 on AWS, standard on
    ##   GKE, AWS & OpenStack)
    ##
    # storageClass: "-"
    accessMode: ReadWriteOnce
    size: 1Gi
    ## A manually managed Persistent Volume Claim
    ## Requires persistence.enabled: true
    ## If defined, PVC must be created manually before volume will be bound
    ##
    # existingClaim:

dashboard:
  enabled: true
  domain: localhost
  serviceType: ClusterIP
  service: {}
    # annotations:
    #   key: value
  ingress: {}
    # annotations:
    #   key: value
    # labels:
    #   key: value
    # tls:
      # - hosts:
      #   - traefik.example.com
      #   secretName: traefik-default-cert
  auth: {}
    # basic:
    #   username: password
  statistics: {}
    ## Number of recent errors to show in the ‘Health’ tab
    # recentErrors:
service:
  # annotations:
  #   key: value
  # labels:
  #   key: value
  ## Further config for service of type NodePort
  ## Default config with empty string "" will assign a dynamic
  ## nodePort to http and https ports
  nodePorts:
    http: ""
    https: ""
  ## If static nodePort configuration is required it can be enabled as below
  ## Configure ports in allowable range (eg. 30000 - 32767 on minikube)
  # nodePorts:
  #   http: 30080
  #   https: 30443
gzip:
  enabled: true
traefikLogFormat: json
accessLogs:
  enabled: false
  ## Path to the access logs file. If not provided, Traefik defaults it to stdout.
  # filePath: ""
  format: common  # choices are: common, json
  ## for JSON logging, finer-grained control over what is logged. Fields can be
  ## retained or dropped, and request headers can be retained, dropped or redacted
  fields:
    # choices are keep, drop
    defaultMode: keep
    names: {}
      # ClientUsername: drop
    headers:
      # choices are keep, drop, redact
      defaultMode: keep
      names: {}
        # Authorization: redact

rbac:
  enabled: true

## Enable the /metrics endpoint, for now only supports prometheus
## set to true to enable metric collection by prometheus
metrics:
  prometheus:
    enabled: false
    ## If true, prevents exposing port 8080 on the main Traefik service, reserving
    ## it to the dashboard service only
    restrictAccess: false
    # buckets: [0.1,0.3,1.2,5]
  datadog:
    enabled: false
    # address: localhost:8125
    # pushinterval: 10s
  statsd:
    enabled: false
    # address: localhost:8125
    # pushinterval: 10s
deployment:
  # labels to add to the pod container metadata
  # podLabels:
  #   key: value
  # podAnnotations:
  #   key: value
  hostPort:
    httpEnabled: false
    httpsEnabled: false
    dashboardEnabled: false
    # httpPort: 80
    # httpsPort: 443
    # dashboardPort: 8080
sendAnonymousUsage: false
tracing:
  enabled: false
  serviceName: traefik
  # backend: choices are jaeger, zipkin, datadog
  # jaeger:
  #   localAgentHostPort: "127.0.0.1:6831"
  #   samplingServerURL: http://localhost:5778/sampling
  #   samplingType: const
  #   samplingParam: 1.0
  # zipkin:
  #   httpEndpoint: http://localhost:9411/api/v1/spans
  #   debug: false
  #   sameSpan: false
  #   id128bit: true
  # datadog:
  #   localAgentHostPort: "127.0.0.1:8126"
  #   debug: false
  #   globalTag: ""

## Create HorizontalPodAutoscaler object.
##
# autoscaling:
#   minReplicas: 1
#   maxReplicas: 10
#   metrics:
#   - type: Resource
#     resource:
#       name: cpu
#       targetAverageUtilization: 60
#   - type: Resource
#     resource:
#       name: memory
#       targetAverageUtilization: 60

## Timeouts
##
# timeouts:
#   ## responding are timeouts for incoming requests to the Traefik instance
#   responding:
#     readTimeout: 0s
#     writeTimeout: 0s
#     idleTimeout: 180s
#   ## forwarding are timeouts for requests forwarded to the backend servers
#   forwarding:
#     dialTimeout: 30s
#     responseHeaderTimeout: 0s
```

Even after setting `kubernetes.namespaces` value, the traefik was watching all the namespaces.

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the answer.

As described here: https://docs.traefik.io/getting-started/configuration-overview/#the-static-configuration

> you can use only one type of static configuration method at the same
>   time.

While setting kubernetes.namespaces value, I was setting the entry of the traefik config file.

I was directly setting the following command-line argument also:

```
startupArguments:
  - "--api"
  - "--kubernetes"
```

This `--kubernetes` command overrides/disables the values set with `kubernetes.namespaces` values.
The default setting of watching all namespaces is applied.

When I commented-out the startupArguments section from the values file, everything started working correctly.